# multiple validation for single cell based on other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Im trying to get a dual data validation working on some cells in an Excel spreadsheet but cant figure out how to get both working at once.

There are two items that are listed, and I need to have it so you can NOT enter a value in B6 if there is a value in A6. Additionally, A6 can NOT be over a value of 49, and B6 can not be less than 50.

I know how to do the number validation separately, and have the below setup as custom to get the either/or setup but can't get both working together

=IF(A6="",TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(B6="",TRUE,FALSE)

thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: So there are **2** conditions on **B6** , but only **1** condition on **A6?**

Comment: No, sorry for any confusion. 

A6 should not be allowed to be filled if B6 already is (while not letting the value in A6 being more than 49).

B6 should not be allowed to be filled if A6 already has (while this value cannot be lower than 50)

Answer (score 0):

You setup the **DV** for **A6** with *Custom > FormulaIs*

```
=AND(COUNTA(B6)=0,A6<50)
```

and similar for **B6**